# What is this white stuff growing on this cacao tree's new leaves?

Tags: trees

This cacao tree has been growing new leaves. White stuff started appearing on the new leaves today:

[image]

[image]

I have absolutely no knowledge of gardening and am asking this on behalf of my girlfriend - what is this stuff, and if it is a problem, how does one remedy it?

Comment: Are they removable? I would guess eggs of some kind, if so. They'll probably hatch soon, if so. Alternatively, it might be a fungus, whether or not they're removable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a waxy sap excreted from the leaf.  It is not a pest but a natural function of the leaf.  I have also seen this on coffee plants and more often on tropical plants that are in high light.